# Visual Studio - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: child

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, crash, windows-forms-designer

When I move a button from the Designer in Visual studio I get this error

[image]

it couldn't be annoying because if I run the solution I do not get any error at runtime, even if in my designer buttons becomes like this:

[image]

and if I try to move the exsisting groupbox (or I try to add a new one) it crashes (visual studio).

How can I debug Visual Studio to understand better my Designer problem? Because when it crashes, Visual Studio close and reopen by itself without asking anything.

Or even is a known bug and there is a simple solution? (but i didn't find anything similar on google)

Comment: What Visual Studio version?

Comment: Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (downloaded from dreamsparks)

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application?

Comment: Yes, this is a Windows Form Application (c#). I'm thinking is a problem inside the Form.Designer.cs because it happens only in 1 form (the project's Main)

Comment: Your designer.cs file is stuffed up at a guess. Put a debug in it where its's building all the controls and step through.

Comment: How can I debug if problem isn't at runtime but when I modify the form with designer?

Comment: Did you try to edit the .designer.cs file? Don't do that.

Comment: Yes, I think you can't debug this unless you debug the designer! VS 2003 had a bug that crashed the designer, the fix was to delete all bin and obj folders. You can edit _Form.Designer.cs_ manually but could take a long time to figure out what's gone wrong. You probably need to rebuild the form, I hope you have a recent older version that was working.